# numpy: maintain decimal class through inverse calculation

Tags: python, numpy, decimal

I'm trying to find the inverse of a matrix made up of a specific class (`decimal.Decimal`) and keep the values as Decimal objects throughout the process (to preserve exactness throughout the calculation).

My problem is `numpy.linalg.inverse` always returns the matrix values as floats. I've figured out a work around by changing the type from floats to Decimal objects after the inverse is calculated but I'd prefer to maintain the class of the original matrix throughout (I'm worried I may be losing accuracy when the numbers are converted to floats)?

So I guess I have a few questions: (1) am I losing accuracy/exactness when the values of the matrix are converted to float types (I'm dealing with an 11 by 11 matrix); if so, (2) is there anyway to keep the values as `decimal.Decimal` throughout the calculation using `numpy`; if not, (3) is there another module / method I should consider for this type of calculation?

Here's an example of what my code will look like:

```
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal as D

a = np.array( [ [D('1'), D('2'), D('3')],
                [D('4'), D('5'), D('6')],
                [D('7'), D('8'), D('9')] ] )

print type(a[0,0])
# <class 'decimal.Decimal'>

inverse_a = np.linalg.inv(a)

print type(inverse_a[0,0])
# <type 'numpy.float64'>

inverse_a_Decimal_flat = [D(str(i)) for i in inverse_a.flat]  # change all values to decimal.Decimal
inverse_a_Decimal = np.reshape(inverse_a_Decimal_flat, [3, 3])  # reshape to 3x3

print type(inverse_a_Decimal[0,0]), d.shape
# <class 'decimal.Decimal'> (3,3)
```

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Not that I'm aware of. 3. Have you tried writing it yourself?

Comment: So if it's exactness I'm after it looks like I may need to use the `np.longdouble` type [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181642/how-set-numpy-floating-point-accuracy?noredirect=1&lq=1). How does this differ from `decimal` in terms of exactness? And it sounds like it will take longer to compute so I'm wondering if it's even worth the trouble. `float64` may be good enough for one step in the calculation (I'm calculating the chemical composition of a mixture).

Comment: If you want exactness, then `Decimal` is not enough - you need `fractions.Fraction`, else you'll end up rounding to some (negative) power of 10. You might want to look into using [`sympy`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/modules/matrices/matrices.html) for infinite-precision matrix algebra

Comment: This matrix is not invertable!

Comment: For a 3x3 matrix, there is  an analytical expression for the inverse.  It's something like the 9 2x2 determinants divided by the full determinant.  Check a symbolic math program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `a` is a object array:

```
In [255]: a
Out[255]: 
array([[Decimal('1'), Decimal('2'), Decimal('3')],
       [Decimal('4'), Decimal('5'), Decimal('6')],
       [Decimal('7'), Decimal('8'), Decimal('9')]], dtype=object)
```

In my newly updated `numpy` I get an error when trying to do an inverse.

```
In [257]: np.linalg.inv(a)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-257-5c2063aa5f16> in <module>()
----> 1 np.linalg.inv(a)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in inv(a)
    524     signature = 'D->D' if isComplexType(t) else 'd->d'
    525     extobj = get_linalg_error_extobj(_raise_linalgerror_singular)
--> 526     ainv = _umath_linalg.inv(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
    527     return wrap(ainv.astype(result_t, copy=False))
    528 

TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting
was found for ufunc inv
In [258]: np.__version__
Out[258]: '1.11.2'
```

`inv` is probably using compiled code (`_umath_linalg.inv`), which will be coded to work with standard `c` floats (float or double).

You asked about `longdouble`:

```
In [266]: a1=np.arange(1,10,dtype=np.longdouble).reshape(3,3)
In [267]: a1
Out[267]: 
array([[ 1.0,  2.0,  3.0],
       [ 4.0,  5.0,  6.0],
       [ 7.0,  8.0,  9.0]], dtype=float96)
In [268]: np.linalg.inv(a1)
...
TypeError: array type float96 is unsupported in linalg
```

Again, it's a question of how `linalg` was compiled.

```
In [269]: a1=np.arange(1,10,dtype=np.double).reshape(3,3)
In [270]: np.linalg.inv(a1)
Out[270]: 
array([[  3.15221191e+15,  -6.30442381e+15,   3.15221191e+15],
       [ -6.30442381e+15,   1.26088476e+16,  -6.30442381e+15],
       [  3.15221191e+15,  -6.30442381e+15,   3.15221191e+15]])
```

I tried to `dot` this and didn't get the expected `np.eye` array.  But this is a nearly singular array (determinant is 0, or nearly so).

```
In [274]: np.linalg.det(a1)
Out[274]: -9.5171266700777698e-16
```

So it's a bad example.

Shuffling values to the array is no longer singular

```
In [288]: a1=np.array([[3,1,2],[4,6,5],[8,9,7]],np.float)
In [289]: a1.dot(np.linalg.inv(a1))
Out[289]: 
array([[  1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   2.22044605e-16],
       [ -4.44089210e-16,   1.00000000e+00,   4.44089210e-16],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00]])
```

I get the same thing if `a1` is `np.int`, since the `np.int` is upcast to `float64`.  I can test with `np.float32` to see the effect of lower precision.  As noted, I can't go to `longfloat`.

`inv` often is calculated as a `I/a1` linear equation solution:

```
In [297]: np.linalg.solve(a1,np.eye(3))
Out[297]: 
array([[ 0.14285714, -0.52380952,  0.33333333],
       [-0.57142857, -0.23809524,  0.33333333],
       [ 0.57142857,  0.9047619 , -0.66666667]])
In [298]: np.linalg.inv(a1)
Out[298]: 
array([[ 0.14285714, -0.52380952,  0.33333333],
       [-0.57142857, -0.23809524,  0.33333333],
       [ 0.57142857,  0.9047619 , -0.66666667]])
```

Comment: I'm using version 1.9.3 -- I'll update and try again. So if this is the case would you recommend converting to `float64` or a different data type for exactness (maybe `np.longdouble`)?

Comment: Any idea what the exactness difference is between `float64` and `np.longdouble` (or `float96` in this case - mine evaluates to `float128`)? Like how many points after the decimal are accurate in each case

Comment: Why are you worried about precision?  Why is important in this problem?  Often taking a standalong `inv` is discouraged.  Instead we are told to use `np.linalg.solve`.  In fact `inv` might actually be implemented as `solve(a,I)`.

Comment: This is one of the steps in calculating the chemical composition of a gaseous solution. I would like to be as precise as possible. Sounds like `float64` should be good enough for this step though (and using `decimal` the rest of the way). `np.longdouble` looks like a headache, may not be supported on some machines and is easy to lose ([Extended Precision at bottom](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html))

Comment: @hpaulj: In particular, `inv` has failed on the original input because the matrix is singular, but `solve` may not

Comment: The singularity of the original array creates these outlandish `e15` values in the inverse.  It's a bad example to test precision on.

Answer (score 2):

Is using [`sympy.Matrix`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/modules/matrices/matrices.html) acceptable?

If we use that:

```
>>> import sympy as sy
>>> a = sy.Matrix([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
>>> a.inv()
ValueError: Matrix det == 0; not invertible.
```

We realize that inverting this matrix doesn't even make sense!

Trying again swapping the 9 with a 10, gives

```
Matrix([
[-2/3, -4/3,  1],
[-2/3, 11/3, -2],
[   1,   -2,  1]])
```

Which is the desired infinite-precision result.