# numpy subtract two arrays: output

Tags: python, numpy

So I want to subtract two numpy arrays a and b:

```
a=[[ 1. 0.85979163 0. 0.11766047 0.19353699]
[ 0.8589698 1. 0.24111901 0. 0. ]
[ 0. 0.24554123 1. 0.09234979 0.07125199]
[ 0.31269982 0.22558714 0.29298401 1. 0.475543 ]
[ 0.18880995 0. 0.06580817 0.32276821 1. ]]


b=[[1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1 1]]
```

When I use the following command:

```
y=numpy.subtract(b,a)
```

I get an output array:

```
y= [[ -2.22044605e-16 1.40208370e-01 1.00000000e+00 8.82339528e-01
8.06463005e-01]
[ 1.41030195e-01 0.00000000e+00 7.58880995e-01 1.00000000e+00
1.00000000e+00]
[ 1.00000000e+00 7.54458767e-01 -2.22044605e-16 9.07650211e-01
9.28748013e-01]
[ 6.87300178e-01 7.74412855e-01 7.07015986e-01 0.00000000e+00
5.24457002e-01]
[ 8.11190053e-01 1.00000000e+00 9.34191829e-01 6.77231787e-01
0.00000000e+00]]
```

And it's really confusing me as to how it's outputting these values.

When I tried to troubleshoot and do:

```
y=b[0,0]-a[0,0]
```

I got y=0.. which makes sense because i would be subtracting 1-1. But in the output array I'm getting a value of -2.22044605e-16 instead.

Do you have any idea as to why this might be happening and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with the data that you provided (I get all 0s on the main diagonal). I hypothesize that `a` is not exactly as you describe it. Perhaps it is a result of another computation, and `1.0` is not exactly `1.0`.

Comment: There is no "fixing it" it is the nature of representing numbers in a computer.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how set numpy floating point accuracy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181642/how-set-numpy-floating-point-accuracy)

Answer (score 2):

`e-16` is essentially `0`. You typically can't avoid numerical precision errors when dealing with floats. But you can always chop the tiny values to 0 exactly afterwards if that's important to you. Note that you probably see `1.` when printing `a` only because numpy doesn't show the full precision by default when printing an array. Try `print(a[0,0])` and you'll probably see something like `1.00000000005`. For example try printing `np.array([1.000000001])` and `np.array([1.000000001])-1`, and `np.array([1.000000001])[0]`...